# How can make dynamic route to look like static route in Next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

Is it possible to do show query routes as static in next.js Router.push function?

I want to do something like this.

```
 Router.push(
   `/statistics?entityId=${id}&entityType=Player&serviceProvider=${serviceProvider}&tab=overview`,
   `/statistics/player/id`,
   {
     shallow: true
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to update the route path with query params without running data-fetching methods again using `shallow-routing`. But the caveat is shallow routing will only work on the same page URL. See the caveats section in the [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/shallow-routing)

So if you try to update `/statistics?entityId=${id}` this is only valid for the `/statistics` page. You can not get the updated query param in `/statistics/player/[id]` page because they are two different pages.

This is valid for `/statistics` page

```
Router.push(
   `/statistics?entityId=${id}&entityType=Player&serviceProvider=${serviceProvider}&tab=overview`,
   { shallow: true }
)
```

So you can either use the shallow-routing in `/statistics` page and use `router.query` to access the updated query params then render the data based on it or you can have multiple dynamic routes like `/statistics/player/[id]`, `/statistics/some-other-entity/[id]`.